# android emulator for large screen xhdpi not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, resolution

I created custom device with configuration- screen size 5.3 inch and 900x1480 resolution.
Then i created AVD with different OS versions, but emulator never launches. It shows up emulator screen but all the time there is only black screen, not even showing "Android". In DDMS LogCat there are going on some actions but for me it looked like its one big loop repeating.

Also i tried to emulate HTC One (normal-xxhdpi) but there is same problem. In this case it may be there isnt updates made to support xxhdpi.

Comment: The emulator is not very good and is full of bugs. The best way to fix the bugs... use real devices to test.

Comment: @TronicZomB: Most developers cannot realistically buy every possible device. That's what the emulator is for.

Answer (score 4):

that happen to me if i set more than 786MB in RAM you should use 512 MB and the emulator will launch

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting "Use Host GPU" in the virtual device settings.